# Apache Camel Split List into bigger pieces

Tags: split, apache-camel

I have a list in exchange object and I want it to be split into objects by the size of ten for ex. Is there any property to set to do that or should I do this manually?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [camel splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) and then the [camel aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html) with a batch size of 10. I would not do this for such a simple case though as the overhead might be substantial. A simple bean or processor with java code to split the data might be simpler.

Comment: but with splitter it is much easier execute this pieces concurrently)